# edit: How can I dynamically create divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a bar graph. I'm having trouble with a bunch of the code, but the biggest problem is that I can't seem to create a loop that will take the data in my sampleData array and create a new div each time and append it to the next div and so on. For now I've simple created 5 divs, but I don't many I will need.

Also, I'd like to hover over the bar and see the number of items.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testMyJson.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
    url:'https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/items?q=Fish&max=20&format=json',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( response ) {
    var sampleData = [25,7,19,22,150];

    //for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $('#super-skill-1').animate( { height:sampleData[0] + 'px' } );
        $('#super-skill-2').animate( { height:sampleData[1] + 'px' } );
        $('#super-skill-3').animate( { height:sampleData[2] + 'px' } );
        $('#super-skill-4').animate( { height:sampleData[3] + 'px' } );
        $('#super-skill-5').animate( { height:sampleData[4] + 'px' } );
    //}


    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Ajax Call Failed - textStatus =" +  textStatus + ", errorThrown = " + errorThrown);
}
});
});
</script>
<style>
.the-container { width:400px; height:250px; border-style: solid; border-width:3px; border-color:black }
.the-container ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
.the-container li { width:30px; height:250px; margin:0 5px; position:relative; float:left; }
.the-container li a { position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:0; background-color:#ccc; }
.the-container li a:hover { background-color:green; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="the-container">
<ul>
<li><a id="super-skill-1" href="#" class="tooltip" title=sampleData[0]></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-2" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-3" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-4" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-5" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<form>
<input type="button" id="showdata"value="Show Data" >


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @elclanrs, I was starting wonder if my question was poorly worded. I'm trying to make a bar graph. I created some sample data, but ultimately I'm getting the data from a web service so I will have no idea how many div's to create for bars. the loop that I commented out doesn't work. It creates 1 bar and resizes it 5 times and stops. I want to create a div (bar) for each item in my sample array so it shows up like a bar graph. Hope that helps??

Comment: So you don't want new divs then do you? you want `li`'s only according to your example

Comment: @wirey, I found this example and thought it might be useful (guess not), because it gave me an example of how to create bars. I'm just learning css, javascript and jquery so my example is probably not showing what I want that well. Can I create bars with hover capability without divs?? I guess I'm confused as to what divs do then??

Comment: check my fiddle below.. is that what you were talking about?

Comment: @wirey, Yes!! Although it's gonna take me a minute to understand it haha. But yes that looks great. Can I easily change it for data from a webservice?? Can I just replace the sample data portion??

Comment: @jc72 it all depends on what format you're sending the data back from the server as.  Best way to troubleshoot is to console.log(data) to find out exactly what your data structure is.  If it's just a simple array then you can just replace the sampleData with the returned data

Comment: @wirey, it will be json data. Also, what is the v in function(i, v)?? I'm assuming the i is for the array number??

Comment: @jc72 check my update.. when you are going through your json data.. in the each function do a console.log(v) to find out what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through and add li/anchor tags dynamically using [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function

```
var sampleData = [25, 7, 19, 22, 150,60,99,56];

$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $.each(sampleData, function(i, v) { // loop through each item in array 
                        //i=indexInArray,v=valueOfElement
        var $lis = $('<li><a></a></li>'); // create new li's with children anchors
        $lis.find('a') // find anchor
            .attr('id', 'super-skill-' + (i + 1)) // add id
            .attr('href', '#') // add href
            .attr('title', v) // add title
            .addClass('tooltip'); // add class tooltip
        $('div.the-container ul').append($lis); // add to ul
        $('#super-skill-'+ (i + 1)).animate( { height:v  } ,1000);  // animate
    });
});​
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sav4Y/)

Comment: Note that it doesn't work for a variable number of array elements as it doesn't show more than 10. Also large values are truncated. See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sav4Y/12/).

Comment: @rsp  Only because the container has limited space.. if you make it bigger it will work fine

Comment: Sure, you can make the chart 3000 pixels high but I doubt this would be very convenient to look at. Since this is an accepted answer and the original poster said in the question that the number of items is unknown and their values are obviously unknown too, I wanted to point out that this solution doesn't work for an **unknown** and **variable** number of values because it doesn't do horizontal scaling and doesn't work for bigger values because it just silently truncates them as I demonstrated with the demo link in the comment above. Of course you can make it 3000 pixel high but...

Comment: @rsp  umm.. all you have to do is make width auto?

Comment: I was talking about the height and width and my point is that a chart on a website that is wider and/or higher than the screen is pretty much useless. You need to scale it appropriately - see [this example](http://jsbin.com/upimuz/6) I just wrote and compare it to [the original example](http://jsbin.com/upimuz/1) from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735391/edit-how-can-i-dynamically-create-divs/12736568#12736568) to know what I mean.

Comment: @rsp, I see your point. At this stage I'm just trying to get something put together to get an understanding of ways to go about doing something like this so all the help is welcome. Thanks for pointers and the gRaphaël info. I'm sure I will be making some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through array can be performed by [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.
To create `div` set from array following methods can be used:

`myArray` - array to create divs for, 
 `#divContainer` - id of element to place new div's in

1) Using [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Good if you need to set attributes or styles applied to new elements

```
$.each(myArray, function(elem) {
      $("#divContainer").append($("<div></div>").css("background", "red").html(elem));
});
```

2) Using string concatenation. Faster than append.

```
var result = "";
$.each(myArray, function(elem) {
        result += "<div>" + elem + "</div>";
    });
$("#divContainer").append($(result));
```

3) Using [jquery.tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) - template plugin for jQuery. Fast and simple way but requires additional plugin

```
$.tmpl("{{each}}<div>{{html $value}}",
       myArray)
 .appendTo("#divContainer" );
```

Comment: Isn't `$.each` just a wrapper for `[].forEach`? It seems way unnecessary to use a library to call functions that you get for free.

Comment: @saml `$.each` is not a wrapper of `[].forEach` and in fact doesn't even use it . See the source code: [core.js lines 566-605](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L566). `Array.prototype.forEach` is not supported on IE6, IE7 and IE8 (see [this table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/#showold) for more info).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the AJAX call to test it. And this seems to work for the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {      
    $('#super-skill-' + i).animate( { height:sampleData[i] + 'px' } );
}
```

I would suggest having the indexes in sampleData match with those in the ids.

```
<li><a id="super-skill-0" href="#" class="tooltip" title=sampleData[0]></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-1" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-2" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-3" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
<li><a id="super-skill-4" href="#" class="tooltip" title="TESTING!!!!"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sample data is coming from the response, (as an array) then you could do

```
for (var i in response) {
    var newDiv = $('<div id="super-skill-'+i+'"/>)
    $('#parentDiv').append(newDiv);
    newDiv.animate( { height:sampleData[i] + 'px' } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not actually answering your question, but a little bonus.

You don't need to add px to animate or css, width, height etc. jQuery assumes px if you leave the unit out.

Yours

```
$('#super-skill-' + i).animate( { height:sampleData[i] + 'px' } );
```

Example

```
$('#foo').animate({top: 100, left: 80 }, 1200);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UqPmB/

Answer (score 0):

## Different approach

Have you considered using a library that was **designed specifically** to draw charts,
like [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)?

Using gRaphaël you just write:

```
r.barchart(10, 10, 400, 250, [sampleData]);
```

and you don't care how many elements you have in sampleData, how to iterate them, how to scale them, what should be a good width of the bars considering their variable number, what would be the maximum value so you know how to scale it vertically, etc.

This is how your program would look like including the values that appear on hover:

[image: bar chart example]

```
var sampleData = [25,7,19,22,150,200,25,77,30,105,5];

var r = Raphael("chart");

// hover handlers:                      
function fin() {
    this.flag = r.popup(this.bar.x, this.bar.y,
                  this.bar.value || "0").insertBefore(this);
}
function fout() {
    this.flag.animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 600, function() {
        this.remove();
    });
}

r.barchart(10, 10, 400, 250, [sampleData]).hover(fin, fout);
```

and that's it.

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/upimuz/1)

(The hover event handlers are a modified version of the handlers from the examples on gRaphaël website.)

It works in Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Comment: never heard of it but man that looks good. I'll have to ask the product owner about using this library but thanks for pointing this out!! If not for this project (we were trying to use jquery to learn) then definitely for something else!

Comment: @jc72 You're welcome. [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) is good not only for charts but also for some graphical effects like for example rounded corners that work on legacy browsers (that don't support modern CSS) and still look good when printed (no pixels). It uses SVG on every browser that supports it and VML on IE. I am surprised that this library is not used more widely. See [this talk by Dmitry Baranovskiy](http://blip.tv/jsconf/dmitry-baranovskiy-rapha%C3%ABl-the-great-3750642) for a good introduction.